# Position and size with copy/paste from Excel to PowerPoint with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I need to copy/paste Excel tables into PowerPoint with VBA.

I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIqoXYy_Clg
The only difference is I want all my tables on the same slide.

When I run the sub, the first two tables are correctly positioned and sized but after the third, they all go into the middle of the slide and the width that I applied changes.

Is there a way to force the tables, after being pasted, to be moved and sized as originally specified.

```vb
Sub ExporttoPPT()

Dim ppt_app As New PowerPoint.Application
Dim pre As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Dim vSheet$
Dim vRange$
Dim vWidth As Double
Dim vHeight As Double
Dim vTop As Double
Dim vLeft As Double
Dim vShape As Double
Dim expRng As Range

Dim Export_PPT_Sh As Worksheet
Dim ConfigRng As Range
Dim xlfile$
Dim pptfile$

Set Export_PPT_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export_PPT")

xlfile = Export_PPT_Sh.[excelPth]
pptfile = Export_PPT_Sh.[pptPth]

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xlfile)
Set pre = ppt_app.Presentations.Open(pptfile)
Set ConfigRng = Export_PPT_Sh.Range("Rng_Sheets")

For Each rng In ConfigRng

    With Export_PPT_Sh
        vSheet$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 4).Value
        vRange$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 5).Value
        vWidth = .Cells(rng.Row, 6).Value
        vHeight = .Cells(rng.Row, 7).Value
        vTop = .Cells(rng.Row, 8).Value
        vLeft = .Cells(rng.Row, 9).Value
        vShape = .Cells(rng.Row, 10).Value
    End With
    
    wb.Activate
    Sheets(vSheet$).Activate
    Set expRng = Sheets(vSheet$).Range(vRange$)
    expRng.Copy
    
    Set sld = pre.Slides(1)
    sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap
    Set shp = sld.Shapes(vShape)
    
    With shp
        .Width = vWidth
        .Height = vHeight
        .Top = vTop
        .Left = vLeft
    End With
             
    Set sld = Nothing
    Set shp = Nothing
    Set expRng = Nothing
   
Next rng

Set pre = Nothing
Set ppt_app = Nothing

wb.Close False
Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have a range on my Excel sheet with all the properties such as width, height etc...
I'm on Excel and PowerPoint 2013.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are getting and what you were expecting?

Comment: That's what I would like to have on the left and how VBA execute it.

https://imgur.com/a/gA7N2Hx

Comment: Ok. Sorry was busy with something. I am not sure what values you have in the cell but to put all images in 1 slide, I would do something like this. `Left:=vLeft, Top:=10, Width:=vWidth, Height:=vHeight` for the 1st shape and then `Left:=vLeft, Top:=Shp1.Top + Shp1.Height + SomeSpaceHeight, Width:=vWidth, Height:=vHeight` for the 2nd shape and so on...

Comment: In my cells I retrieved the exact position that I wanted my tables, that way, in theory the tables should appear at the right place.
But my question is that with your solution I cannot do a loop in VBA, I have to specify each shape place in the VBA. Therefore it's not really practical for me, because the number of tables or the places might move and it would be easier to be in Excel cells instead of VBA.

Comment: If you create a custom layout with content placeholders positioned as you want the tables to appear, VBA will automatically paste them into that arrangement. Create the placeholders in the order that you want VBA to fill them.

Comment: Thank you very much John. The placeholder is indeed the solution, I added the code here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282466/paste-a-chart-from-excel-to-a-specific-placeholder-in-a-specific-layout-powepoi and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to John Korchock I tried to use Placeholders instead of defining the width, heigth etc...

That way, the tables always go as the intended place and size. The code finally looks like this :

```
Sub ExporttoPPT()

Dim ppt_app As New PowerPoint.Application
Dim pre As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Dim vSheet$
Dim vRange$
Dim vPlcHolder As Long
Dim expRng As Range

Dim Export_PPT_Sh As Worksheet
Dim ConfigRng As Range
Dim xlfile$
Dim pptfile$

Set Export_PPT_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export_PPT")

'Path of the PowerPoint template and the excel worbook.
xlfile = Export_PPT_Sh.[excelPth]
pptfile = Export_PPT_Sh.[pptPth]

'Opening the excel and ppt workbooks
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xlfile)
Set pre = ppt_app.Presentations.Open(pptfile)
Set ConfigRng = Export_PPT_Sh.Range("Rng_Sheets")

'Variables
For Each rng In ConfigRng

    'Set Variables for tables 
    With Export_PPT_Sh
        vSheet$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 4).Value
        vRange$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 5).Value
        vPlcHolder = .Cells(rng.Row, 6).Value
    End With

    'Export tables to PPT
             wb.Activate
             Sheets(vSheet$).Activate
             Set expRng = Sheets(vSheet$).Range(vRange$)
             expRng.Copy
    
             Set sld = pre.Slides(1)

                  With shp
                      
                     sld.Shapes.Placeholders(vPlcHolder).Select msoTrue
                     sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap
                   
                  End With
          
        Set sld = Nothing
        Set shp = Nothing
        Set expRng = Nothing
   
Next rng

Set pre = Nothing
Set ppt_app = Nothing

wb.Close False
Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

It's may be not the most optimized code, but at least it works everytime without going as the wrong place.

Thank you again for the comments !